# GWT StockWatcher sample app -- cannot find CSS

Tags: html, css, eclipse, gwt

I'm sorry.  This has to be one of those second-pair-of-eyes things, and I'm just not finding it.  I am attempting to go through the GWT tutorial that has a fake "StockWatcher" application, and it isn't applying my style sheet, and I do NOT know why.

I am using eclipse (Kepler); I am on windows 7; I develop this in eclipse and run it from there, and the app does run.  Now I'm at the point where we're going through what the style sheet can do for the app, and it not only doesn't appear to see the stylesheet, it seems to use a DIFFERENT stylesheet file that I cannot find on my computer.

I open this in Chrome, and use "Inspect Element".  The window there does not support multiple-line selection, so copy-and-paste would be quite tedious.  Suffice to say that the version of the HTML file shown in Chrome has the following:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="StockWatcher.css">
```

I saw a warning on the web about closing the  tag, so I changed that in my source to have " />" at the end.  I've cleaned and built it, and restarted the server, twice now, but the unclosed tag still appears in the HTML shown by Chrome.  What do I have to do to get the updated version of the HTML in use?

Before I corrected that, Chrome's "inspect element" allowed me to open StockWatcher.css, and it had different lines in it than the lines I put there.  I searched the entire hard drive for another StockWatcher.css and didn't find one; does the GWT build make a war file that I have to do something special to update?

I tried changing the encoding on the HTML to UTF-16 from UTF-8, but it still (of course) says UTF-8 when I look at it in inspect element.  I guess getting the updated version of the files to be the ones that run is my first problem...

What am I doing wrong?

This is the HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the     -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into                -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration   -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype is not supported. -->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <!--                                                               -->
    <!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
    <!--                                                               -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="StockWatcher.css" />

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- THIS is fine                         -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <title>StockWatcher</title>

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
    <!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
    <!-- be added before this line.                -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="stockwatcher/stockwatcher.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <!--                                           -->
  <!-- The body can have arbitrary html, or      -->
  <!-- you can leave the body empty if you want  -->
  <!-- to create a completely dynamic UI.        -->
  <!--                                           -->
  <body>

    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>

    <h1>StockWatcher</h1>

    <div id="stockList">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is StockWatcher.css itself:

```
/* Formatting specific to the StockWatcher application */

body {
  padding: 10px;
}

/* stock list header row */
.watchListHeader {
  background-color: #2062B8;
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

---

Here are the "Program arguments" for the eclipse run configuration; obviously they are on one line in the configuration:

> -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher 
>   -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" 
>   -startupUrl StockWatcher.html 
>   -logLevel INFO 
>   -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 
>   -war C:\Users\rcook\workspaceKepler\StockWatcher\war
>   com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.StockWatcher

Comment: How do you run the project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS file is located in the /war directory in your project. This is the only copy that is needed, and the only copy that your app will use.

There must be something wrong with the way you launch your app in Eclipse. Open a Run Configuration that you use. Check that there is a correct path to your /war directory in Arguments tab.

Comment: I have added the run configuration to the original post, above.  Something else I noticed: in Chrome, where I'm looking at the wrong copy of the CSS file, there is a button I had not noticed called "Navigation"; when I click that, it shows 127.0.0.1:8888, and underneath that stockwatcher, and underneath that StockWatcher.css and StockWatcher.html?gwt.Codeserver=127.0.0.1:9997 as files (i.e., this Navigation looks like a file chooser dialog).  If I open THAT css, it is the wrong one, i.e., it doesn't match the one in my project source.  Does anyone know where it is, and how to update it?

Comment: The run configuration is correct. What URL do you use to access the app? it should be http://http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html?gwt.Codeserver=127.0.0.1:9997

Comment: yes - http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997, to be exact.

Comment: I use GWT for many years, and I never saw this problem. Typically, you  make a change in a CSS file, hit the refresh button in a browser, and you can see all changes right away. There is no caching, and no second copy of the CSS file anywhere.

Comment: Is there any difference if you launch it in a Debug mode or Run mode? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802621/gwt-development-with-eclipse/14802846#14802846.

Comment: There IS a difference if I refresh the browser -- evidently rebooting my machine is not enough.  Then the CSS file in the Chrome inspector looks like chinese; I changed the encoding specified in StockWatcher.html from UTF-16 to UTF-8, and pressed F5 in the browser, and NOW the CSS is taking effect.  I gather that restarting the server was NOT enough; I had to refresh the browser as well.  Thanks for your help, and your perseverence.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same probelm too. I just used maven clean and install to update the resources,and it works now. I think the problem is that your old resources are always in you project. I hope this can do you some help. :)